# Preventing user from viewing page more than 3 times

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, web, server-side

Is there anyway to prevent a viewer from viewing a certain page more than three times? I'm currently using cookies created with the JQuery Cookie plugin. So far it works well, but I know that the user can simply clear/erase cookies and access the page again. Is there any better alternatives to tracking and prevent users view more than once? Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript is definitely not the best way to prevent a page from viewed 3+ times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could require that the user authenticate before they can see the page at all.  Then on the server side you could track how many times the given authenticated user has requested the page.  I doubt that any other mechanism would not be circumventable.

Comment: This is more or less the answer I was going to post. Even with user accounts, you'd need to prevent the user from signing up more than once.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Jake! I'm just starting out with the entire server-side world :S.

Comment: Yes, there will have to be something done to verify uniqueness of accounts, but that is a separate problem that could be addressed in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 0):

How about capturing users IP Address and storing them and use a counter?

Comment: There are so many ways for that to both lock out a legitimate user and allow an unscrupulous user to game the system:  proxy servers, NAT, DHCP, viewing from multiple locations, etc.

Comment: I've usually turned away from doing this aswell but ruleing cookies out I couldn't think of another approach.  And finding loop holes everyone will try it if its to their advantage no matter what security you try to enforce with username and password.

Comment: There are mechanisms like justin.tv that detect proxies and others that detect how many hours you've spent watching videos from their servers..so there is a way it would just take researching or trial and error.

Comment: I've personally defeated some of those video steaming sites that monitor your usage, with a simple socks proxy over SSH. So, no - there really is no failsafe way of preventing it, without authentication.

Comment: Also - don't forget that in this day and age, everyone has a smartphone with a data plan.  They could easily switch over to that to hit the same site from a different IP.

Comment: I agree @JakeFeasel it's quite dificult to prevent without authentication but if he cannot or does not want to use authentication it doesn't leave you with many options does it?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to store it server side, probably by ip address in a database.